# UIScrollView contentInset property not auto-scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am working with a UIScrollView and am unable to auto-shift the content when I change the view's contentInset property. I had this working before, but after making several changes to my app (including implementation of auto-layout) the auto-scrolling no longer works (for my specific case, I am shifting my content when the keyboard appears). The contentInset is in fact changing; and I am able to manually drag the content to where I expect it to be. I have been troubleshooting for hours and cannot figure out where I am going wrong! Are there any special considerations to take with UIScrollViews and autolayout in order to have contentInsets work appropriately?

Thank you!